# Keycloack share resource with Group of user

Tags: keycloak

I am new to keycloak, I'm studying the examples and I know how to create and manage resources, but I don't understand how to share them with a group of users.

A little example: user Alice create resource R1, how can i share resource R1 with all the user of group X?

I'm watching the PermissionTicketRepresentation class, but it seems related to a single user?

can i do this? How?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a resource then you should create [Permission](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_permission_create_resource) and apply [Policy](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_policy_group) to it. Permission defines protected resources and policies that should be used. The policy defines actual rules - e.g "user belongs to group" or "user has the role", etc.

Comment: Yes, but in this way, i don't know when a user have a resource shared with him, because, i've made only one rule that regulate the permission between Group and a specific Resource.

I need one function Like the **photoz** example, when an **album** is shared with one **user**, how can the user share a resource with a group?